# Rails 3.2 validating string inclusion default value not detected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I am using mongoid with a model field and given validation:

```
field :status, type:String, :default=>'Active'
validates :status, :inclusion=>{:in=>%w(Active, Done, Canceled, Merged)}, :allow_nil=>true, :allow_blank=>true
```

in the form, I do not have the status field, so it's supposed to be not POST-ed therefore it's nil on creation:

```
= simple_form_for([@user, @task], :html => {:class=>'form-horizontal',:'data-type'=>'html'}) do |f|
  - if @task.errors.any?
    .error_explanation
      .alert.alert-error
        The form contains
        = pluralize(@task.errors.count, 'error')
      %ul
        - @task.errors.full_messages.each do |msg|
          %li=msg
  .form-inputs
    = f.error_notification
    = f.association :project, :collection => current_user.projects.all
    = f.input :description, :as => :text, :input_html => {:rows => 5}
    = f.input :priority, :as=>:radio_buttons, :collection=>1..4, :item_wrapper_class=>'inline'
    = f.input :due_date

    .control_group.select.optional
      = f.label :assigned_to, :class=>'select optional control-label', :for => 'assigned_to_id'
      .controls
        = f.collection_select :assigned_to_id, User.all, :id, :username, :class => 'select optional'

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, :class => 'form-button btn-primary', 'data-loading-text' => 'Submitting...'
```

however, I am still getting this despite setting a default value "Active", which is obviously in the array provided for the validation of inclusion:

```
Status is not included in the list
```

why am I still getting this error?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is your issue

```
%w(Active, Done, Canceled, Merged)
```

which translates to

```
["Active,", "Done,", "Canceled,", "Merged"]
```

solution is to remove the commas

```
%w(Active Done Canceled Merged)
```

Comment: I knew I was missing something so simple! Thanks!

Comment: we all have that one moment where all we need is a fresh set of eyes :)